# Trouble with horizontal and vertical lines accepting class "Date" in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a Gantt chart in ggplot based on the generous code offered by user Didzis Elferts. I'm trying to add a vertical line showing today's date, but the `geom_vline` layer in the `ggplot2` package simply returns `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. Here is my code:

```
    today <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")
    library(scales)
    ggplot(mdfr, aes(time,name, colour = is.critical)) + 
      geom_line(size = 6) +
      xlab("") + ylab("")+
      labs(title="Sample Project Progress")+
      theme_bw()+
      scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 year"))+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=today))
```

The plot without the `geom_vline` command looks like this [image: plot]:

Any reason why `geom_vline` wouldn't work for the "Date" character?

EDIT: Reproducible code used to generate plot:

```
    ### GANTT CHART 1 ###############3
    tasks <- c("Meetings", "Client Calls", "Design", "Bidding", "Construction")
    dfr <- data.frame(
      name        = factor(tasks, levels = tasks),
      start.date  = c("07/08/2013", "07/08/2013", "07/23/2013", "08/30/2013", "9/30/2013"),
      end.date    = c("07/12/2013", "07/13/2013", "08/15/2013", "09/12/2013", "12/01/2013"),
      is.critical = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))

    mdfr <- melt(dfr, measure.vars = c("start.date", "end.date"))
    mdfr$time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(mdfr$value,"%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Provide a reproducible example please.

Comment: Done. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two thinks you need to change in your code.

First, as for making the `time` column in `mdfr` you use `as.POSIXct()` the same should be done with `today` - both variables should have the same format.

```
today <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Second, use `as.numeric()` inside the `geom_vline()` around `today`.

```
  + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(today)))
```

Comment: Dude, so simple, yet so effective. Thanks for your help.